# Back-channel reference checks : what can be done if you find out?

Tags: united-kingdom, references, hiring

Back-channel reference checks can cost you a job.

If you find out / get verbal confirmation that a former colleague did NOT recommend you for a new job, is there anything that can/should be done about it?

(by not recommending I mean: negative, negative feedback)

Comment: What would you want to do about it? Is your issue here that the former colleague was lying (potentially of course) or that they didn't tell you what hoped they would say while what they said was true? I.e. was the negative feedback justified?

Comment: Was this a reference that you provided or was the hiring person asking around the office and the former colleague gave their feedback? Both have different connotations

Comment: What do you mean, what can be done? What's your objective here?

Comment: I'm tempted to revoke the bounty and cast the final closure vote here. It's still not clear to me what exactly you're asking and what specific scenario is in play here: who found out what about whom? To get high quality answers you need a well-phrased question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what they do in the UK, but in the US, a lawyer will hire a third-party employment verification background checking service (the same ones that employers use) to check what they say about you.

If the third-party service comes back with a report that is overtly negative, then the lawyer will threaten the person in question (or if the person is still with your former employer, the lawyer will threaten your former employer with legal action). I first heard about this from Nick Corcodilos at https://www.asktheheadhunter.com/

But you must consider four things:

- Some employers are very good at probing references. And a reference doesn't have to say anything explicitly negative about a former employee, but the way they answer questions can still be pretty telling if the person asking the questions reads between the lines.
- If a backchannel was used between two old acquaintances, there is probably very little you can do about that. It's very difficult to prove anything.
- If your former boss is willing to badmouth you to a third-party service, that is the most damaging to you, but this is also the easiest scenario to prove.
- The UK has some of the [strongest](https://www.hrmguide.co.uk/law/defamation.htm) anti-defamation laws in the world. So don't take what we say about your situation here too seriously, since most of us are in the US. You should really be consulting an employment/defamation solicitor within your own jurisdiction.

Now, if the person is still employed by your former employer, I suppose you could complain to the general counsel or the HR department of your former company. And those folks will most likely refuse to officially believe this happened, but privately they will most likely advise the person in question not to say anything about you, positive or negative, but to just forward any request for information directly to HR. That being said, depending on the person, that may not be enough. And if the person in question has already left your former employer, that's not going to work either.

Comment: At least in the USA, I'm having trouble picturing anyone doing any badmouthing directly to a 3rd party service.  That's been drilled into employees for years: all companies can say is "so and so worked here during this time period".

Comment: @JoeStrazzere, "the truth is always a valid defense" - I agree with you. That's why I am emphasizing that the laws are different in the UK. **In the UK**, the truth is **not** always a valid defence. See https://www.npr.org/sections/parallels/2015/03/21/394273902/on-libel-and-the-law-u-s-and-u-k-go-separate-ways

Comment: @DaveG If it's "back-channel", it's probably informal, meaning the parties are less likely to be... regimented... in their answers.

Comment: "When Mr X worked here, many were willing to comment on his work.  Mr X demonstrated the importance of good hiring practices and after he left, we discussed the possibility of hiring another employee like him.  He was never caught sleeping on the job, and the impact he had on the company during his tenure cannot be understated"    A reference like that, while not defamatory is full of enough double entendre to make it very clear

Comment: @Old_Lamplighter, Exactly.

Answer (score 4):

No. There is nothing that can be done.

In the future, try to get as much written documentation as you can, including things that prove previous work history, and written (positive) references.

Some HR teams may find written documentation sufficient, and you may avoid a phone call that way.

Obviously you should not write the names of previous managers, unless they agree to give you positive references.

Comment: I think this depends on whether the feedback was true or not. If it were maliciously untrue, there _might_ be a case for libel and consequent damages. My limited understanding is that this would be establishing a precedent in English law though.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Of course. But practically speaking, the new employer (who now probably doesn't want anything to do with the OP) would have to go to court as a witness and testify what was said. I just don't see it happening.

Comment: @PhilipKendall And yeah, there are like a heap of different questions potential employers  know to ask to get honest feedback: "Would you hire this person again?" "Not in a million years." Probably the most blunt indictment, and not legally actionable.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest it's very unusual for someone in the UK to give a very bad reference. I would speak to ACAS:

https://www.acas.org.uk/contact

Here is there official advice:

https://www.acas.org.uk/providing-a-job-reference/if-you-get-a-bad-reference

<s>I would phone them and speak to someone who should be able to give more specific advice. For the next time you should check with the "referencee" first.</s>

Ok so it seems that I didn't understand what is meant by a backchannel reference. If your current company just randomly asked someone you know then actually the same rules still apply.

If they defame you i.e. make unsubstantiated claims about you that lose you your job then you can take them to court (In the UK).

In terms of the company doing this unfortunately I can't see anything illegal about that but I would speak to ACAS about this as it's unusual not to ask for permission.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie I'm not sure that actually matters if someone gives you a very bad reference then there is every chance you can sue them for defamation. That is only if they have said something that they cannot substantiate with some evidence. Again I would talk to ACAS they deal with this type of thing all the time.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie No my fault I get you i'll edit

Answer (score 0):

Of course I am giving the copout answer.... it depends.

There might be some legal recourse you could pursue, but it will very very difficult to prove AND it also depend on the type of negative feedback that was given. Back when I worked in Puerto Rico (almost 25 years ago), I assumed a supervisory position at the place I used to work when I lived there. The company sent me to take a seminar and one of the things that were discussed were legal matters "bosses" needed to be aware of. In those seminars I learned that, according to Puerto Rican law, an employer is legally forbidden to offer details as to why a particular employee no longer worked there. According to the law, an employer can only disclose

1. If the employee worked there (confirm dates of employment), and
2. Whether or not the employee is rehireable. This last question can
   only be answer with a yes or no. No additional details could be
   given... Not even if the employee quit or was fired.

In the unlikely event that you find out that these laws were broken, you might have an avenue to pursue legal action. TO MY RECOLECTION, I do not remember them mentioning anything about peers or subordinates being forbidden to provide details about your employment with a company.

I currently live in Texas and I have employees under my direct supervision, but companies don't seem to train employees in supervisory positions on the legal aspects of the job. That said, I am convinced that the laws here in Texas are very in favor of employers. So, I won't be surprised if they could provide negative details about your work history with a given company.

Now, future employers don't typically contact anyone that is not on your professional references. So, if one of them decide to spill the beans on you, then I guess you kind of deserve it for not being selective as to who you put on that list. I have friends I have known for years, decades even, and I always contact them to see if it is OK to list them as references. What I won't do is ask anyone I am not 100% sure of and list them as a reference.

That is what I know on the subject. Now, I believe that if what has been said is disclosed to you AND is egregious enough (and of course, false) you might have legal recourse for slander (and/or libel). Again, those are really hard to prove for what I have heard. I am assuming that in the U.K. there are laws regarding slander and libel. So, if there are no regulations like the ones I mentioned Puerto Rico has to protect employee's rights, you could (alternatively) purse other avenues like slander.

Answer (score -2):

> If you find out / get verbal confirmation that a former colleague did NOT recommend you for a new job, is there anything that can/should be done about it?

The best advice is to ask your former colleague if you can add them as a reference. Usually when they say "ok" they indirectly stating they will give you a favorable reference. If they did a jerk move and said "ok" and then back stabbed you by giving a bad reference, then don't use them anymore. It is generally not a good idea to leave a reference of a person you did not speak directly to.

However, if you did not ask them or if you came from a hostile work environment, my advice is not to give any numbers to an employee/manager and instead give your new employer the number to a verification hotline, which nearly all businesses have (smaller ones may not). Your previous employer from an official standpoint, usually won't disclose opinions and will stick with factual information such as your employment status, termination dates, and perhaps, though probably not, your final pay amount.

Depending on your age and work history, it may be best to leave the previous job out of your resume. If it was a short term job of a couple of months, for example, you can (almost) safely remove it and the gap won't be too noticeable.